# Cookie does not work in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, safari

I have written a simple div, which hides when user clicks (X) button. And does not appear next time when user gets back to the website if he has closed the div before. All this logic is stored using cookies. And works perfect in chrome and firefox but not in safari.

My javascript code to store cookie info:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var cookie = document.cookie;
    if (cookie.indexOf('subscription=', 0) !== -1) {
        $('#pushDown').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $("#pushDown").slideDown("slow");
    }
    $("#close").click(function(){
        var cookie = document.cookie;
        var expiration = new Date();
        expiration.setDate(expiration.getDate()+1);
        document.cookie = 'subscription=1;expires=' + expiration + ';path=/';
        $("#pushDown").slideUp("slow");
    });
});
```

NOTE: to simulate browser refresh click run several times. [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Jacck/90/)

Maybe someone know there the problem cood be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
'subscription=1;expires=' + expiration + ';path=/';
```

to

```
'subscription=1;expires=' + expiration.toGMTString() + ';path=/';
```

Comment: I had the same issue, but already had `expiration.toGMTString()`. After a while I figured out was due `,` used as separator for fields (strangely it was working on Chrome, FF and IE). I've put `;` and works like charm.